# XBee digital input for digital sensor

Tags: input, sensors, digital, xbee

Is possible to use an XBee module to capture the value of a [DHT11 digital sensor](http://www.adafruit.com/products/386)? 
If I set the DIO1 to digital input I should receive the value into two bytes, but if the sensor returns more than two bytes how is possible to read the value using an XBee module?

Comment: ok, i think i can use Xbee digital input only for one HIGH or LOW value, and not for reading a digital sensor value like (11000101011001011010); is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to decode a signal like that, you would need a secondary processor.  You might want to take a look at [Digi's Programmable XBee modules](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/zigbee-mesh-module/xbee-zb-module?tab=productdocs&pid=4624#docs), which include a Freescale HCS08 processor for additional code that you write.  The adafruit page says that it, "requires careful timing to grab the data."

There's sample code on the Digi web page titled, "Developing Timer-Based, Bit-Banged Pulses with the Programmable XBee".